# TFS Error after an upgrade and downgrade

Tags: tfs

I upgraded to TFS 2013 Update 5 however, its errors left right and centre and to cut a long story short, Ive reverted back to the original install with databases intact.

Everything works fine except the work item views, where i get this error:

```
Method 'GetVariableValue' in type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.ServerWiqlAdapterHelper' from assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.DataAccessLayer, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
```

[image]

The DLL exists in this folder :
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\Plugins

Any ideas on how I can resolve this problem? work items are displayed fine through Visual Studio just not the web interface.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed using information from this post. http://msdev.developer-works.com/article/30377522/TFS+Web+Access+is+broken

'This is the location of the offending file:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Replace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Workitemtracking.common.dll with version 12.0.31101.0 with a time stamp of 4/23/2015, the visual studio 2013 update 5 is what broke this, you can pull this off of a machine that does not have visual studio update 5 yet. '

replaced the DLL - works fine now

Comment: I had the same error after installing a clone of our TFS installation on a different machine. This solution worked fine, using the dll from the source machine. Many thanks!
However, the link to the post is broken.